What is the best solution if the website is the same but needs to target Google.de and Google.at?
Following situation: I run an online shop, which is currently targeting Germany and Austria using the same domain "mydomain.at". In Austria (google.at) the SEO is strong, but in Germany (google.de) my website is not even indexed.
My idea to solve it was like this: .at for Austria, .de for Germany. But I am kinda confused since it's the same website. I know, I can use hreflang, but since my Wordpress/Woocommerce shop is using the .at domain, how can I make it run with .de also? If I use a 301 redirect from .de to .at, it will always show .at, right? How can I make it run with both? Domain alias? Or is it a bad idea? Both domains are in Plesk. Austria and Germany have the same language, and we have the same prices also, therefore, there is no need for a multistore. But I have no idea how I could ensure that the current Google.at SEO doesn't get lost, but that I can become indexed in Google.de with the .de domain. Really confusing all! 

If you hadn't already launched, I'd say .com would perhaps be the best solution.  I assume the .at is just too much of a signal to rank in Germany. .com may still be the best approach, but there's a bit more risk now the site is established.

Thank you for your reply. Yeah, it has been launched already with ".at" and it's SEO ranking for austria is great. Indeed ".com" might have been better if done in the begining. But on the other hand, in google.at and google.de ".com" domains are not ranking that well. So I believe google.at prefers .de/.at domains, google.de prefers only .de.

The fact that you state that your website is not indexed in google.de despite the same language might indicate that you messed up the language targeting. You should have a look at the language set for the pages and make sure it's set to "de" without any region like "de-AT". In addition you should check for hreflang markup and make sure it is not present at all or correctly states "de" (would also work for Switzerland) or "de-AT" and "de-DE".

Thanks, Schwarz, I will check on this!
